# Find lowercase words in Groovy

Tags: regex, groovy

I recently started learning Groovy. 
I have a small task: get all lowercase words from string as List

I wrote next code:

```
public List<String> findWordsInLowercase(String string){
    return string.findAll(/\b[a-z]+\b/)
}
```

It work. But i want to do it without regex, because it's very difficult to read, understand and remember.

Now i try to write same function without regex. My code:

```
public List<String> findWordsInLowercase(String string){
        def words = string.split()
        words.findAll
                {it ->  for(Character character in it)
                        character.isLowerCase()}
    }
```

But it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than checking every character, why not check the word is the same as it's lowercase representation?

```
public List<String> findWordsInLowercase(String string) {
    def words = string.split()
    words.findAll { word ->
        word.toLowerCase() == word
    }
}
```

Or, it might be more understandable to make your first function:

```
public List<String> findWordsInLowercase(String string) {
    string.findAll( /\b\p{javaLowerCase}+\b/ )
}
```

Which should improve readability, and you don't need to remember it, as you now have a function ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use meta programming to *extend* `String` class and then use this *extension* in normal method:

```
String.metaClass.isLowerCase = { 
    delegate ? delegate.every { it.toCharacter().isLowerCase() } : false
}

public List<String> findWordsInLowercase(String string){
    string.split().findAll { it.isLowerCase() }
}

assert findWordsInLowercase('AAA bbb') == ['bbb']
```